# Power MUX Circuit with 5V & 3.3V Regulation + Reverse Polarity Using LM358 - Questions & Concerns

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, multiplexer, reverse-polarity, hysteresis

I'm working on a circuit that can be powered via USB or via header pins.

The goals are:

1. The MUX will determine, and prioritize, the higher voltage supply.
2. The MUX will provide reverse polarity and reverse current protection to the power input sources.
3. To ONLY regulate (via LDO) voltage which is above a predetermined threshold. *This feature is to accommodate input voltages which are already regulated at, or near, the target board voltage without incurring an additional voltage drop from the LDO.*

I've drawn the below schematic, including power input protection, utilizing P-channel mosfets as ideal diodes, for reverse polarity and reverse current.

I have some concerns before I build and test this circuit, as I rarely fiddle with Op Amps, and have yet to use the LM358.

I understand that the working voltage range of LM358 begins at 3V - utilizing the device for 3.3V (3.6V) voltage compares is a tight fit. I've also added diodes to all op amps to ensure reverse polarity protection of the op amps and circuit, as I suspect that current can flow in reverse through these devices based on information found in the datasheet (*see below*). I will choose diodes with a low forward drop for this application.

> Precautions should be taken to insure that the power supply for the integrated circuit never becomes reversed in  polarity or that the unit is not inadvertently installed backwards... https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/LM358.pdf

My real concern is whether the LM358 op amps are a good fit for this application, and whether they will work as expected in this circuit.

**All feedback from those more experienced and familiar with the LM358, and op amps, will be greatly appreciated.**

**Furthermore, I would like to hear if hysteresis compensation should be added in this type of circuit application.**

[image: Power MUX Voltage Regulation with LM324]

Comment: it is normally bad juju to use an op-amp as a comparator. if you want a comparator - use a comparator. Something like a lm339? You're also assuming the zener diodes as 'perfect' zener diodes. Real ones and especially low voltage ones behave quite different.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Kartman, just looking at the datasheet now - it's definitely looking to be a better fit.